# Wand and a staff differences in Portal Knights

Tags: portal-knights

What are the fundamental differences between a wand and a staff in Portal Knights?

It seems that staffs have higher damage, but I'm not sure if they have a lower fire-rate than wands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After now having spent some time using both a wand and a staff in the game, I am providing the significant differences I have found between the two.

1. Wand projectiles fly straight, while staff projectiles fly in an arc and take longer to reach the target.
2. Wand fire rates are significantly higher than staff fire rates.
3. Wand bonuses seem to be around critical hits while staff bonuses seem to be around mana regeneration.
4. Wand base damage tends to be lower than the base damage of a comparable staff.